# Como converter o tamanho da imagem para o formato A4 com iTextSharp

Tags: c#, itextsharp

Por favor, estou gerando várias imagens em um único PDF e esta rodando corretamente.
 O que não consigo é deixar no tamanho A4 as imagens  pois elas ficam muito grandes tipo 80% do tamanho padrao.  Como posso diminuir para encaixar no A4?
o Código está abaixo.
Grato

```
iTextSharp.text.Document Doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4, 80, 80, 80, 80);
            //Salve o documento
            string PDFOutput = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "C:\\Users\\Usuario\\Desktop\\imagensParaPDF\\Output.pdf");
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(Doc, new FileStream(PDFOutput, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read));
```

Comment: O que o programa faz é ler um diretorio onde tem imagens .jpeg e convertê-las em um único PDF

Answer (score 2):

Utilize o `ScaleToFit`.

No meu exemplo coloquei uma imagem, no formato `Bitmap` (`imagemConvertida`),  setei o tamanho que eu queria com o `ScaleToFit` e deixei ela justificada com o `Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED`.

**Exemplo:**

```
iTextSharp.text.Image imagem = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imagemConvertida, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
imagem.ScaleToFit(600f, 300f);
imagem.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED;
document.Add(imagem);
```